# How to verify download link

Tags: c#, selenium

From this window

[image]

I have a code:

```
Assert.AreEqual("Your download link is ready.\1ae81c15120f4b86b6562531583942eb.zip", driver.FindElement(By.Id("zipdwnlnk")).Text);
```

The part of the code similar to this 1ae81c15120f4b86b6562531583942eb is generated randomly.

This part can include almost anything with a ".zip" extension.

How to verify if download link is created ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[0-9a-f]{32}
```

it will match the random guid-like number you've generated in your link.

https://regex101.com/r/BwW5lV/2